# Solving an Exponential Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm having a hard time with this exponential equation, I'm sure I'm doing some kind of a "minor" mistake again somewhere along the way. Your help is very much appreciated.

$$4\cdot4^{2x}-9\cdot 4^x+2=0$$

**Answers given are:* $0,5; -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=4^x$. The equation
$$4\cdot4^{2x}-9\cdot 4^x+2=0$$
$$4\cdot(4^x)^2-9\cdot 4^x+2=0$$
becomes a quadratic
$$4y^2-9y+2=0,$$
which we can solve with the quadratic formula. Then, once you've found the two values for $y$, solve for $x$ using $y=4^x$.

Comment: Oh! I forgot about that. Thank you again Zev!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!